# How can woocommerce recent products shortcode be edited so that is returns product attributes?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the recent products shortcode for the Woocommerce plugin and it returns the product image, title and price. All of my products have more attributes which I would like to be returned as well. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom loop like this:

https://www.philowen.co/blog/show-latest-woocommerce-products-in-your-template/

Either create it as a custom shortcode or action depending on where your planning to pull this in and have the attributes pulled in using products class within the loop:

```
<?php
$product = new WC_Product;
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();

foreach loop...

?>
```

Something like:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'stock' => 1,
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'orderby' =>'date',
'order' => 'DESC' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?>
global $product;
    // Get the attibutes
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    // Loop and display the value
    // var_dump $attributes to see what you can output
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
          echo $attribute['value'];
    }

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps to some extent. The solution in the link only shows me how to display the image, title and price. I'm still confused as to how I can access other attributes of woocommerce products e.g. if I was selling cars I would want to display the mileage in the recent products section.

Comment: Try something like the above, let me know if you get any errors & the var_dump.